# Sorting specific columns randomly

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, shuffle

I have a file that looks like this:

```
1   90042011    90042031    AGTGCCACCAGGTGGGGCCG    90042029    2   5008    G:5006  T:2     90184334    90184354    GAGGCCACAAGAGGGCACAA    90184337    2   5008    C:5007  T:1
1   94853396    94853416    GCCGCCACTAGATGGTGCTA    94853398    2   5008    T:5007  C:1     94969254    94969274    CAGTCCTCTAGAGGGAGCCC    94969266    2   5008    G:5006  A:2
2   103584283   103584303   TGGGCCACTAGGAGGCACTG    103584300   2   5008    C:5006  T:2     103841436   103841456   CATGCCACAAGAGGGCATCA    103841456   2   5008    A:5006  G:2
3   67156478    67156498    TGGACCACCAGGTGGCAGTA    67156492    2   5008    A:3308  T:1700      67316925    67316945    CTGACCACCAGAGGGCAACA    67316942    2   5008    C:5004  T:4
4   106206208   106206228   AAGGCCAGAAGAGGGCATCA    106206210   2   5008    C:5007  T:1     106381214   106381234   CGTGCCAGCAGAGGGCGGTG    106381217   2   5008    A:5007  G:1
4   106511652   106511672   GCGGCCTCTAGGGGGCACTG    106511672   2   5008    C:5000  T:8     106836794   106836814   TCCACCAGTAGAGGGTACTA    106836796   2   5008    G:5007  T:1
4   107410713   107410733   GTGGCCAGCAGGGGGCACTC    107410725   2   5008    T:5007  G:1     107517764   107517784   CTCTCCACACGGGGGCGCCC    107517769   2   5008    G:654   GAGAGGTATTCCCT:4354
```

I want to write a script that treats values from `$10` to `$17` as one line, and randomly shuffle them, values from `$1` to `$9` just as they were. So the output would look something like this:

```
1   90042011    90042031    AGTGCCACCAGGTGGGGCCG    90042029    2   5008    G:5006  T:2     107517764   107517784   CTCTCCACACGGGGGCGCCC    107517769   2   5008    G:654   GAGAGGTATTCCCT:4354
1   94853396    94853416    GCCGCCACTAGATGGTGCTA    94853398    2   5008    T:5007  C:1     103841436   103841456   CATGCCACAAGAGGGCATCA    103841456   2   5008    A:5006  G:2
2   103584283   103584303   TGGGCCACTAGGAGGCACTG    103584300   2   5008    C:5006  T:2     106381214   106381234   CGTGCCAGCAGAGGGCGGTG    106381217   2   5008    A:5007  G:1
3   67156478    67156498    TGGACCACCAGGTGGCAGTA    67156492    2   5008    A:3308  T:1700      90184334    90184354    GAGGCCACAAGAGGGCACAA    90184337    2   5008    C:5007  T:1
4   106206208   106206228   AAGGCCAGAAGAGGGCATCA    106206210   2   5008    C:5007  T:1     94969254    94969274    CAGTCCTCTAGAGGGAGCCC    94969266    2   5008    G:5006  A:2
4   106511652   106511672   GCGGCCTCTAGGGGGCACTG    106511672   2   5008    C:5000  T:8     67316925    67316945    CTGACCACCAGAGGGCAACA    67316942    2   5008    C:5004  T:4
4   107410713   107410733   GTGGCCAGCAGGGGGCACTC    107410725   2   5008    T:5007  G:1     106836794   106836814   TCCACCAGTAGAGGGTACTA    106836796   2   5008    G:5007  T:1
```

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: `paste <(cut -f1-9 file) <(cut -f10- file | shuf )`

Comment: I've used sort -R and shuf, but I think that shuffles the whole line based on provided columns. I do not know how to exactly shuffle as I want. Still very new to this.

Comment: @choroba yes thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you got a solution to your problem but in the future, please reduce the size of your test data to 80 chars or less. Your problem could have easily been illustrated with fewer columns of data. That just makes it easier for readers to copy/paste to their local environment for testing. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the columns are tab separated, you can use `cut` to extract the columns to keep and the columns to shuffle, then use `paste` to glue them back:

```
paste <(cut -f1-9 file) <(cut -f10- file | shuf )
```

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle scripts borrowed from [[ here ]](https://github.com/e36freak/awk-libs/blob/master/shuf.awk), below script is stored in a file

```
$ cat shuffler.awk
# actual shuffle function
# shuffles the values in "array" in-place, from indices "left" to "right".
# required for all of the shuf() functions below

function __shuffle(array, left, right,    r, i, tmp) {
  # loop backwards over the elements
  for (i=right; i>left; i--) {
    # generate a random number between the start and current element
    r = int(rand() * (i - left + 1)) + left;

    # swap current element and randomly generated one
    tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[r];
    array[r] = tmp;
  }
}
## usage: shuf(s, d)
## shuffles the array "s", creating a new shuffled array "d" indexed with
## sequential integers starting with one. returns the length, or -1 if an error
## occurs. leaves the indices of the source array "s" unchanged. uses the knuth-
## fisher-yates algorithm. requires the __shuffle() function.
function shuf(array, out,    count, i) {
  # loop over each index, and generate a new array with the same values and
  # sequential indices
  count = 0;
  for (i in array) {
    out[++count] = array[i];
  }

  # seed the random number generator
  srand();

  # actually shuffle
  __shuffle(out, 1, count);

  # return the length
  return count;
}

NR==FNR{
for(i=1;i<=9;i++){fp[NR]=fp[NR] OFS $i}
for(i=10;i<=17;i++){sp[NR]=sp[NR] OFS $i}
}
END{
shuf(sp,spnew)
for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)
 print fp[i] spnew[i]
}
```

Running the script like below :

```
$ awk -f shuffler.awk casefile_48424159 | column -t
1  90042011   90042031   AGTGCCACCAGGTGGGGCCG  90042029   2  5008  G:5006  T:2     94969254   94969274   CAGTCCTCTAGAGGGAGCCC  94969266   2  5008  G:5006  A:2
1  94853396   94853416   GCCGCCACTAGATGGTGCTA  94853398   2  5008  T:5007  C:1     103841436  103841456  CATGCCACAAGAGGGCATCA  103841456  2  5008  A:5006  G:2
2  103584283  103584303  TGGGCCACTAGGAGGCACTG  103584300  2  5008  C:5006  T:2     90184334   90184354   GAGGCCACAAGAGGGCACAA  90184337   2  5008  C:5007  T:1
3  67156478   67156498   TGGACCACCAGGTGGCAGTA  67156492   2  5008  A:3308  T:1700  67316925   67316945   CTGACCACCAGAGGGCAACA  67316942   2  5008  C:5004  T:4
4  106206208  106206228  AAGGCCAGAAGAGGGCATCA  106206210  2  5008  C:5007  T:1     106381214  106381234  CGTGCCAGCAGAGGGCGGTG  106381217  2  5008  A:5007  G:1
4  106511652  106511672  GCGGCCTCTAGGGGGCACTG  106511672  2  5008  C:5000  T:8     107517764  107517784  CTCTCCACACGGGGGCGCCC  107517769  2  5008  G:654   GAGAGGTATTCCCT:4354
4  107410713  107410733  GTGGCCAGCAGGGGGCACTC  107410725  2  5008  T:5007  G:1     106836794  106836814  TCCACCAGTAGAGGGTACTA  106836796  2  5008  G:5007  T:1
```